# Automatically invoking PHP code after asynchronous celery task is finished (celery-php)

Tags: php, python, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Celery to schedule asynchronous tasks (processing time= 2-3 minutes) (the tasks are implemented in python, but they are being delegated from a PHP code using [celery-php](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php)), and it was working fine, until I needed to process some PHP code automatically after a task finishes, so I can't just send a request to Celery to fetch the results.

However, I did a workaround to do that by sending an HTTP request by the ending of the processing from the celery task, which I know it's bad because it might create a bottle-neck on the PHP server (not to talk about the security issues that will require some maintaining).

My question is: is there any way to invoke PHP code from Celery using the same backend it is using and having PHP code as a passive participant? if there is not, is there a way to make this call scheduled in the same way the task itself is scheduled to avoid performance overhead?

Answer (score 0):

This probably answer your question http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.amqp.celery.user/3954 .
I would also suggest, if possible, to consider the possibility to rewrite the PHP code in Python.